# How can I merge two array values in java script

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var array= [
    {
      "Name": "mohan",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor"
    },
    {
      "Name": "mahesh",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor1"
    },
    {
       "Name": "manoj",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor2"
    }]

var array2= [
    {
      "Name": "mohanraj",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "manojkumar",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor2"
    },
    {
       "Name": "mohankumar",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor3"
    }];
```

expected output

```
array3=[
 {
      "Name": "mohan",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor"
    },
    {
      "Name": "mahesh",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor1"
    },
    {
       "Name": "manoj",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor2"
    },
{
      "Name": "mohanraj",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "manojkumar",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor2"
    },
    {
       "Name": "mohankumar",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor3"
    }
];
```

Comment: You're not merging anything, you're just concatenating 2 arrays. Use the `concat()` method.

Comment: Try this one: 
`const array3 = array.concat(array2);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```js
const arraymain = [
    {
      "Name": "mohan",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor"
    },
    {
      "Name": "mahesh",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor1"
    },
    {
       "Name": "manoj",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor2"
    }]
const arraysecond = [
    {
      "Name": "mohanraj",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "manojkumar",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor2"
    },
    {
       "Name": "mohankumar",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor3"
    }];
const arraythird = array3=[
 {
      "Name": "mohan",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor"
    },
    {
      "Name": "mahesh",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor1"
    },
    {
       "Name": "manoj",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor2"
    },
{
      "Name": "mohanraj",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "manojkumar",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor2"
    },
    {
       "Name": "mohankumar",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor3"
    }
];
const arrayfinal = arraymain.concat(arraysecond,arraythird);

console.log(arrayfinal);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array3 = array1.concat(array2):
```

See [Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Answer (score 0):

```
const array3 = [...array1, ...array2]
```

this will do shallow copy, which will avoid reference issues upto a level.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`Array.prototype.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method  which allows to append value of one array to another Array

```js
let first_array = [1,2,3,4];
let second_array = [5,6,7,8];

let results = first_array.concat(second_array);
console.log(results);
```

In you case you can perform that this way

```
let array3 = array.concat(array2):
```

Answer (score 0):

The Array() constructor is used to create Array objects. You can create the third array by passing the elements of the first and second array elements as arguments. You could do that by using the spread operator.

```
let newArray = new Array(...firstArray, ...secondArray)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it very important to take your time learning the basics of Javascript.There ar 1000 ways to achieve this.

```
var array= [
    {
      "Name": "mohan",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor"
    },
    {
      "Name": "mahesh",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor1"
    },
    {
       "Name": "manoj",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor2"
    }]

var array2= [
    {
      "Name": "mohanraj",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor1"
    },
    {
      "Name": "manojkumar",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor2"
    },
    {
       "Name": "mohankumar",
      "DESCRIPTION": "Vendor3"
    }];

//Without ES6
var arr3=array.concat(array2)

//With ES6 syntax
cons arr3=[...arr,...arr2]
```

For the rest learn the basics of Javascript...